# AspNetUsers descendants: Tree View MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, recursion

I'm figuring out how to get all descendants of a user.
**AspNetUsers** table is as follows:

```
Id Name ReportingTo(Foreign Key to AspNetUsers table)
1  P1     2
2  P2     3
3  P3     null
4  P4     2
5  P5     3
6  P6     7
7  P7     null
```

And if I want to get all the users under **P3** then they would be **P2,P1,P4,P5**
But while using recursive technique I'm not able to figure out.

Also in my MVC project I'm using `AspNetUsers1` as reference wrt LINQ hence if I do `AspNetUsers1` for `P3` then I would only get objects for `P2,P5`

***Current Code*** (This goes upto only 1 level down and I want it to be until there are no AspNetUsers1)

```
AspNetUser userObj = context.AspNetUsers
.Where(m => m.Email == "P3@domain.com").FirstOrDefault();
List<AspNetUser> desList = userObj.AspNetUsers1.ToList();
```

Comment: you may need to add the code in the Post which gives you only P2, P4.

Comment: @SonalBorkar Done

Comment: check out this link https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/966/is-this-recursion-linq-example-inefficient

Comment: This type of question (recursive LINQ) is being asked maybe once or twice a week. Are you sure you couldn't find an answer?